# C++ – reversing a two-letter character array yields an unknown behavior?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a simple program which prompts user for a word, then inputs that word onto a char array as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a;
    char s[1024],r[1024];

    cout<<"Enter a string:";
    cin>>s;

    for(int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        a = i + 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        r[i] = s[a-i-1];
    }

    cout << r;

    return 0;
}
```

As you will soon see, inputting a 2-letter word will produce an unexpected behavior, any other length of word is ok.

For instance, I tried inputting "Hi". Instead of the expected output "iH", it yields "iH?" where ? is any random symbol.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is your first loop meant to do something like the one-liner `a = strlen(s)+1;`?

Comment: You forgot to copy the terminating null Byte. Why don't you work with std::string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget to terminate the string in `r`. That means the output of `r` will go on after the characters you copy from `s` until it finds the terminator `'\0'`, possibly going out of bounds of the array.

This is bad because local non-static variables, including arrays and their contents, will have an *indeterminate* value, and reading this data leads to undefined behavior (as will going out of bounds of an array).

There are two simple solutions: The first is to initialize the `r` array to all zeroes:

```
char r[1024] = { '\0' };
```

the other is to add the terminator after the copying loop:

```
r[a] = '\0';
```

Comment: Great answer, got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you just declare `r` without initializing, `r` contains garbage. After replacing some value of `r` you don't terminate it by a null character `'\0'`. Hence printing `r` will occur undefined behavior.

So put a `'\0'` in

```
r[a] = '\0';
```

this will terminate the string `r`.

[Run live here.](http://ideone.com/1QE1xB)

Input:

> Enter a string: ab

Output:

> ba

Read about [Null Terminated String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

Answer (score 1):

You are not copying the `\0` byte, because your loop exits when the 0-byte is reached (end of string) which doesn't include it. Since `r` is not initialized, it contains random characters cuasing an undefined behaviour as there may not be a 0-byte present.

So either do

```
memset(r, 0, sizeof(r));
```

before copying or terminate the string after the copy is done with a 0-byte at the appropriate position.

```
r[a] = 0;
```

or another alternative is:

```
 for(int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    a = i + 1;

a++;   // One additional char to account for the 0-byte.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `STL` and in particular `std::reverse` in the first place:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char s[1024];

    cout << "Enter a string:";
    cin >> s;

    std::reverse(s, s + strlen(s));

    cout << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Thus, you could reverse an arbitrary sized string.